# « Part-time job » en français ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction

J'ai besoin de traduire *Part-time job* pour le mettre dans mon CV. Il s'agit d'un stage qui est de 20 heures par semaine. En anglais, normalement on décrit cela comme « part-time job » ou « part-time internship ». Comment le dire en français ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Travail à temps partiel » est le terme qui correspond.

Answer (score 1):

En complement, dans un tel cas on peut consulter linguee :

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/part+time+job.html

On y voit : *emploi à temps partiel*. Du coup, *half-time job* est *emploi à mi-temps* :

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/half+time+job.html

Une autre solution est Deepl. Ex.

https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/part%20time%20job

On y retrouve

> *travail à temps partiel*
>
> *emploi à temps partiel*
>
> *travail à mi-temps*
>
> *emploi à mi-temps*